# Using map<string,int> to use strings in switch-case statements

Tags: c++

Since we can't use strings in switch-case statements directly, as they can't evaluate to constants, I mapped my entries in a `map<string,int>`.

```
map<string,int> hash;
    hash["+x"] = 0;
    hash["-x"] = 1;
    hash["+y"] = 2;
    hash["-y"] = 3;
    hash["+z"] = 4;
    hash["-z"] = 5;
```

Now, I am using them in the switch-case expression :

```
cin >> bend //assume user entered +x
switch(hash[bend])
            {
                case hash["+y"] :
                    switch(pointedto)
                    {
                        case hash["+x"]: pointedto = hash["+y"];
                            break;
                        case hash["-x"]: pointedto = hash["-y"];
                            break;
                        case hash["+y"]: pointedto = hash["-x"];
                            break;
                        case hash["-y"]: pointedto = hash["+x"];
                            break;
                        case hash["+z"]: pointedto = hash["+z"];
                            break;
                        case hash["-z"]: pointedto = hash["-z"];
                            break;                  
                    }
            }
```

I am getting errors :
`an array reference cannot appear in a constant-expression` for all the `case`s. I was expecting `hash["+x"]` and others, to return `int` which will result in a constant.

PS : the other alternative is `constexpr` from `C++11` but I was curious to use this one.

Comment: A constant expression is something that can be evaluated at compile time. `std::map::operator[]` is not one of those things.

Comment: _I was expecting hash["+x"] and others, to return int *which will result in a constant.*_ What make you expect has["something"] will result in a constant=

Comment: It *is* possible to create a map which can be indexed by strings yielding constant expression. Creating it takes a bit of effort. My [CppCon 2016](https://cppcon.org/2016program/) showed how to create a basic version. The [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/CPP/CppCon-2016/CppCon-2016-Dietmar-Khl-Constant-Fun) is linked from my Developer Story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't fight the language.

The case labels in a C++ `switch` statement need to be *compile time evaluable constant expressions*, and a C++ standard library `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` doesn't currently provide that.

Use an `if` `else` block instead. It might even wind up faster - particularly if you pick an optimal order.

`switch`ing on a *character array* (e.g. `'+x'`; note the single quotation characters) is often mooted as an alternative for 4 characters or less, but even that is not portable.

Comment: Meh, you're right. If you ask me, the only place to use switch would be over enum values.

Answer (score 4):

The problem in this particular code example is that the `case` value should be a compile-time constant. Value returned by `std::map::operator[]` is not, so it cannot be used in the `case` clause.

You could use the `constexpr`-based approach, like this:

```
constexpr array<double, 10> values = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0};

constexpr int f(double f) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (values[i] == f) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

double x = 4.0;
switch (f(x)) {
case f(1.0) :
    break;
case f(2.0) :
    break;
    ...
default :
    break;
}
```

But it works only for `constexpr`-constructible types. Unfortunately, `std::string` isn't one of them.

Comment: Woah... why did I ignore that one? On one-side I am talking `constexpr` and on other side I am expecting `switch-case` to be predictive. I think I should go to bed now :O

Comment: Java allows switching on strings by the way. But it would be a shame to lose yet another C++ guy to the dark side.

Answer (score 1):

A few solutions:

1. Get rid of the strings as early as possible. Declare `enum direction {posX, negX, posY, negY, posZ, negZ}` and declare `pointedto` to be of type `direction` rather than a string. Now you can say `case posY:` which is compile-time constant, but more readable than `case 2:`. Change `hash` to a `map<string, direction>` to parse input from the user, do all your processing using `direction`, and define a `map<direction, string>` to translate back to string when you want to present an answer to the user.
2. Recognise that searching a map is "kinda like" a switch. A switch that contains a nested switch could be emulated by a map of maps (`map<direction, map<direction, direction>>`) so that *all the switches could be replaced* with one line: `pointedto = hash[bend][pointedto];` OR the nested switches could be replaced with one map with a "compound key" (`map<pair<direction, direction>, direction>`) so that all the switches are replaced by `pointedto = hash[make_pair(bend, pointedto)];`. This will work with `bend` and `pointedto` as strings - so `hash["+y"]["+x"] == "+y"` - but if you are doing a number of iterations between user input and output, enums may be more efficient.
3. Declare an enum with cleverly selected values, for example, `enum direction {posX=4, negX=0, posY=5, negY=1, posZ=6, negZ=2}` and find some clever maths to transform bend and pointedto to a new pointedto value. **NOTE:** The values I have illustrated here were just made up for illustrative purposes - and this route should only be used if you really need to optimise this code for performance. I mention this route for completeness' sake, but take no responsibility for sleepless nights if you decide to go with it :)

**EDIT**

4. This:

```c++
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

enum direction {posX, negX, posY, negY, posZ, negZ};

const direction transform[6][6]{
    // previous pointed to:                    bend
    // +x    -x    +y    -y    +z    -z        ----
    {                                   },  //  +x
    {                                   },  //  -x
    { posY, negY, negX, posX, posZ, negZ},  //  +y
    {                                   },  //  -y
    {                                   },  //  +z
    {                                   },  //  -z
};

const std::map<std::string, direction> stringToDirection{ { "+x", posX },{ "-x", negX },{ "+y", posY },{ "-y", negY },{ "+z", posZ },{ "-z", negZ } };
const std::map<direction, std::string> directionToString{ { posX, "+x" },{ negX, "-x" },{ posY, "+y" },{ negY, "-y" },{ posZ, "+z" },{ negZ, "-z" } };

int main(int, char**) {
    direction pointedto = posY;

    std::string bendInput;
    std::cin >> bendInput;
    direction bend = stringToDirection.at(bendInput);

    pointedto = transform[bend][pointedto];

    std::cout << directionToString.at(pointedto) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- You have to fill in the rest of the array initialisation.
- In this example, I have no error checking on the user input.
- `directionToString` should be generated from `stringToDirection`, but I wanted to keep things simple here.